# I'm trying to locate the column index from a row but keep getting errors, i'm new to using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

SOLVED

```
import pandas as pd

firstNameDB = str(firstNameInput())
surNameDB = str(surNameInput())
with open('userdb.csv', mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    if (firstNameDB and surNameDB) in f.read():
        print('You are a pre-existing user on the database, '
              'let me load your details for you')
        data = pd.read_csv('userdb.csv')
        df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Firstname', 'Surname', 'Hours'])
        print(df)
        dfRow = df[df['Firstname'].str.match(firstNameDB)]
        print(dfRow)
```

the CSV is just a basic first name, surname, number file. My code currently checks if the user is already in the database. I'm trying to code a way to locate the index of the `Hours` column so I can call the data at (x,y) where x is the index integer of the row and y is the column number. the data at this location will then be fed through some calculations

Comment: Are you trying to get the row location instead of the index label? I’m not sure this is entirely clear, can you provide more context for the task? Why are you creating a DataFrame from the result of `read_csv()`? Also, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the index of the column?

```
>>> df.columns.tolist().index('Hours')
2
```

Comment: yeah that's great thanks! i thought i was missing something out like that

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is

```
dfRow = df[df['Firstname'] == firstNameDB and df['Surname'] == surNameDB]
```

I wouldn't do the "with open" or the "if (firstNameDB and surNameDB) part.  Just read in the csv to a dataframe and use the line above to find the row (or rows) that match.

Edit: I misread your question, but hope these suggestions still help you.